# convolution of binomial and poisson distribution

Tags: probability, convolution, moment-generating-functions

The transforms associated with two independent discrete random variables X and Y are $M_x(s) = (\frac{1}{2} {e^2}^s + \frac{1}{2} {e^4}^s)^7, M_Y(s) = e^8(e^s - 1)$  Find P(X + Y = 15).

This is what I have so far:
$(\frac{1}{2} {e^2}^s + \frac{1}{2} {e^4}^s)^7 = {e^{14}}^s(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}{e^2}^s)^7 \quad$
let W~Binomial(7,$\frac{1}{2})\quad$  then X=2W+14 $\quad$
Also Y~Poisson(8)

Now P(X + Y = 15) = P(2W + Y = 1) , 2W~Binomial(14 , $\frac{1}{2}$)$\quad$
Let Z = 2W + Y $\quad P_z(k) = \sum_{k = 0}^{14} P_x(k)P_y(z-k) = \sum_{k = 0}^{14} \binom{14}{k}{2}^{-14}\frac{{e}^{-8}{8}^{z-k}}{8!}$

I'm stuck here. I used the summation calculator and the answer doesn't seem right. Please let me know where do I get it wrong or perhaps there's a better way to approach?

Comment: Sorry being lazy to check your generating functions. If you obtain the correct distribution for $W, X, Y$, then at the step $\Pr\{2W + Y = 1\}$, it is equivalent to $\Pr\{W = 0, Y = 1\}$ as $W, Y$ only take values on non-negative integers. And by independence it is done.

Comment: Oh my. You're right. thanks